# What is the mode of $Z=\sqrt{X-Y}+4$? Given $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: random-variables

Given that $$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 \text{X} & 2 & 6  \\
\hline
 \text{p} & 0.3 & 0.7 \\
\end{array}$$
and 
$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 \text{Y} & 1 & 2  \\
\hline
 \text{p} & 0.1 & 0.9  \\
\end{array}$$

What is the mode of $Z=\sqrt{X-Y}+4$?

So far I have got that:

$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 \sqrt{X-Y}+4  & 4 & 5 & 6 & \sqrt{5}+4  \\
\hline
 \text{p} & 0.03 & 0.27&0.63&0.07  \\
\end{array}$$
(Am I right this far?)

If one would ask for mode of this random variable $Z$ would it be correct to say that mode is ${4,5,6,\sqrt{5}+4}$?

EDIT:
Discard the last question, I forgot, that I have to look for value of $Z$ that has the highest probability.

I guess the mode would be $\sqrt{5}+4$, because of it's $0.63$ probability, right?

Comment: Except that you've mixed up which value of $Z$ has what probability, yes, you're correct (it's $Z = 6$ that has probability $0.63$, since it corresponds to $X = 6$ and $Y = 2$).

Comment: Thank you, Now I got it right!